# PyQt5 QMdiArea Tabbed Subwindows Management Issue?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

**Description:**

I'm using PyQt5 to create a multi-document interface (MDI) application with QMdiArea for managing multiple subwindows in a tabbed view. However, I'm facing an issue with subwindow management.

**Problem Statement:**

Initially, I can open subwindows as tabbed views within the QMdiArea by clicking on corresponding buttons (e.g., "Educatinal).
When I close a subwindow using the "x" button or the close button, it closes smoothly, and the corresponding tab is removed.
However, when I attempt to reopen a previously closed subwindow by clicking on the corresponding button again, the subwindow appears outside the QMdiArea as an independent window, rather than as a tabbed view within the area.
I expect the reopened subwindow to appear as a tabbed view within the QMdiArea, just like it did initially.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

open_sub_windows = {}

class ClosableMdiSubwindow(QMdiSubWindow):
    aboutToClose = pyqtSignal(str)
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            obj == self.widget()
            and event.type() == event.Close
            and obj.close()
        ):
            self.removeTab(self.widget())
            self.close()
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        if self.widget() and self.widget().isHidden():
            self.widget().show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        subwindow_name = self.objectName()
        self.aboutToClose.emit(subwindow_name)
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def removeTab(self, widget):
        for i, sub_window in enumerate(self.mdiArea().subWindowList()):
            if sub_window.widget() == widget:
                self.mdiArea().removeSubWindow(sub_window)
                break


class Educational(QWidget):
    closeRequsted = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Educational Details")
        self.btn_close = QPushButton("Close")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel("subjects"))
        self.layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Physics"))
        self.layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Maths"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_close)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


dict_link_itemwise = {"Educational": Educational}


class MdiSubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Mdi and SubWindow Examples")
        self.open_sub_windows = {}  # Dictionary to store open subwindows
        self.ui()

    def ui(self):
        self.Hbox_page = QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn_Educational = QPushButton("Educational")
        self.Hbox_page.addWidget(self.btn_Educational)
        self.btn_Educational.clicked.connect(self.open_subwindow)

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.mdi.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdi.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdi.setViewMode(QMdiArea.TabbedView)
        self.mdi.setTabsClosable(True)
        child = self.mdi.findChild(QTabBar)
        child.setExpanding(False)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.Hbox_page)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.mdi)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def open_subwindow(self):
        page_name = self.sender().text()
        if page_name in open_sub_windows:
            sub_window = open_sub_windows[page_name]
            sub_window.show()
        elif page_name in dict_link_itemwise:
            page_widget = dict_link_itemwise[page_name]()
            sub_window = ClosableMdiSubwindow()
            sub_window.setObjectName("obj_" + page_name)
            sub_window.setWidget(page_widget)
            open_sub_windows[page_name] = sub_window
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub_window)
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()
            sub_window.show()
        else:
            print("Invalid page class:", self.page_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MdiSubWindow()
    app.setStyle("Windows")
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are removing the subwindow from the mdi area, if you want to show it again there, you must call `addSubWindow()` again.

Comment: @musicamante, pls calrify, my approach,whether its  is correct or worng

Comment: I don't understand your objective. In your previous question you created new instances of the widget (Education) every time whenever they were closed, now you want to delete the subwindow. It seems like you're randomly trying alternatives until you find what you like while not knowing how the MDI API works, trying to fix things and changing approach/behavior in the meantime. You are probably unsure about what you actually want and you're trying to understand things at the same time, which may be understandable, but also not very productive, as it slows down *both* development *and* learning.

Comment: I may be having the wrong impression, though, so, if you **do** know what you actually want and how the program should behave, then please clarify it, otherwise you'll be continuing to ask *wrong questions* (read about the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). If, instead, you're still unsure about what you want, I suggest you to take your time and clarify these aspects before. Then try to implement the *concept* (not based on the actual program code) using *simple* tests, while (or, better, *after*) patiently studying the API documentation.